# Using the Rally API to re-rank multiple stories

Tags: rally

I'd been looking at using the Rally API to create an app to do some simple auto-ranking stories based on specific criteria (at the request of / to help out a couple of our Product Owners) in a drag&drop workspace.

I did this by adjusting the "Rank" properties of the sequence of stories (I made sure to keep the rank values within the same overall min / max range as prior to the auto-reorder).  I made a call to the API to update each story's rank individually (in quick succession).

Testing the app, I found that sometimes after running the auto-ranking app, some screens (such as the kanban board) would tell me that "drag and drop re-ranking is disabled for manual rank workspaces" (and the kanban would no longer let me drag & drop, although other screens such as the backlog would still let me drag & drop, and the workspace settings were still set to drag & drop).  Deleting the stories, or reordering them on the backlog screen would return things back to normal.

After trying a few ideas to solve this, I figured perhaps if I was updating the Rank on a number of stories in quick succession, the back-end might be getting confused with these (potentially several / concurrent) requests.  Introducing a delay between each story's API call has seemed to avoid the problem, and to speed things up, I now update a story's rank in the API only after the previous story's rank update has invoked the "updateComplete" function.

Do the assumptions in the last paragraph above make sense based on the backend ranking?  Is there any Javascript API call to update multiple stories at once?  (Otherwise I'm quite happy with the solution of only calling the API "update rank" after the prior API "rank update" call has returned ok).

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you discovered a possible issue with the backend ranking.  The warning you were getting stems from the board trying to figure out which type of workspace you are in (manual or dnd rank).  Since that setting is not currently available via WSAPI the board tries to figure it out based on its data and sometimes gets it wrong.

Currently there is no fully supported/documented way to adjust the ranks of items via WSAPI.  The Card Board component in the App SDK uses special rankAbove and rankBelow query string parameters during update calls (which you can see in Firebug or the Chrome dev tools).

How are you currently setting the Rank values?

Comment: Interesting.  From JS, I'm just doing                       rallyDataSource.update({"_ref": item._ref, "Rank": newRank}, onUpdateComplete, onUpdateError);

Comment: Just to follow up on this, I've also successfully used this technique for a long time from a ruby app, per'item.update(:rank => newRank);' (although this ruby app only ever changed 1 story's rank at any one time, as opposed to my new JS app, changing multiple story's ranks): I have a vague recollection that the rank field (per the API docs) a long time ago might have been defined as read-only, but I'm not sure this has been the case for a long time.